# Pros and Cons of AMF in multiplayer flash game?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, multiplayer

After trying to use red5 for my turn-based multiplayer game, I've decided to give AMF a try using amfphp, because of the expensive media server hosting solutions. (With AMF all I need is a web server). The game is a simple turn based game. It uses Box2D for physics. Its similar to pool or billiards. More than two users should be able to play in one game 'table'. Is it OK to use AMF in this situation? Also which one should I use? ZendAMF or AMFPHP?

Features: No. of players >= 2 in each 'room' or 'table', turn-based, multiple rooms.

I've heard games like farmville use AMF. Does zynga's poker game also use AMF? How does one player get info on what the other player is doing? Do they do a timed checking for any changes, similar to polling? How can changes or 'moves' made by one player be updated to everyone? Since the connection is terminated after every request unlike in a socket connection.

Comment: You have edited in several more questions which aren't directly related to your initial question.  I suggest you create a new question for these, I'm sure you'll get better answers that way.

Comment: As I read more I get more questions sadly. Since they're related I try to bunch em up together. I see u've answered many of my questions. Thank you.

Comment: It's ok that you have more question. I was just suggesting you put them in a separate question, chances are better you get an answer that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a normal web hosting, you won't be able to run socket connections. So your game has to constantly fetch the updates from the server by issuing a HTTP request. For a turn-based game this might be ok, but probably won't work if you want to simulate your pool billiard on the server and update the clients (to prevent cheating).

Now as for which AMF implementation to use: AMFPHP is quite easy to setup and get going, but AFAIK it's no longer actively developed. If you have some experience with the Zend Framework (or would like to learn it), definitely stick with the Zend version.